# Filtering data from large table using where clause returns 'response too large ...' error

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to filter some data using 'where' clause from a table that has more than 1.2 TB of size and about 2.8 billion of rows.

I started testing data filtering with small data table (~21 millions of rows and 9.6 of table size) by setting a destination table and enabling 'Allow Large Results' in job configuration.

My query is very simple :

```
SELECT * FROM [mydataset.mytable] Where DATETIME >= '2014-03-17 00:00:00' and  DATETIME <= '2014-03-17 23:59:59';
```

I used both BigQuery Browser Tool and bq command line tool, however, I get the 'Response too large to return' error every time I run this query.

In the documentation here http://goo.gl/b6pNjA, Google says:

> - If you plan to run a query that might return larger results, you can    set allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.
> - You must specify a destination table.
> - You can't specify a top-level ORDER BY clause.
> - Window functions can't return large query results.

My query is very simple and does not include any window functions. So, to bypass this problem, is there a specific query syntax that can I do to run my query successfully?

Please note that here at http://goo.gl/zkSN32, it is specified that the Maximum response size is 128 MB compressed and unlimited when returning large query results as explained at the above link (http://goo.gl/b6pNjA).

Comment: I mean... it tells you right in that doc you quoted.... *'If you plan to run a query that might return larger results, you can set allowLargeResults to true in your job configuration.'*

Comment: In the BigQuery Browser Tool, I enabled the 'Allow Large Results' option and I did the same thing in bq command line, but it returns always 'response too large' error.

Comment: I'm not super familiar with the system, but is it's possible the problem is displaying the result, rather than fetching it? I.E. it states that you *'You must specify a destination table'*, which would imply that you have to store the result somewhere, you can't just print it out or hold it in-memory.

Comment: yes, of course! in the job configuration, I enabled the 'Allow Large Results' option and I set a destination table where the result will be stored after the query execution. However, the error persists.

Comment: does it happen also if you state all fields in the select phrase instead of using * ?

Comment: It works fine when I replaced select * by select field1, field2, field3, ..., fieldn.

Thanks N.N. for this trick. It is very much helpful!

Comment: This sounds like a bug; can you provide a job id for one of your failed queries so that we (the BigQuery team) can investigate the issue?

Comment: This is the id 'job_zuO09ot5Jn9ixF2AVW1OqtHRxGc' of one of my failed queries.
thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As N.N says, to avoid the 'Response too large to return' error in this case, it should state all fields in the select clause instead using select *.

I tried running the same query by stating all fields in the select statement, setting a destination table and enabling 'Allow Large Results', and it works fine.

Query complete (115.6s elapsed, 298 GB processed).

Number of Rows of destination table:    77,796,259.